# Necessary and sufficient condition for a subset of $\mathbb{N}_2$ to be a base set

Tags: real-numbers, normal-number

This is a follow-up to my previous question several years ago, here: [Can a number be normal in an arbitrary set of bases?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161218/can-a-number-be-normal-in-an-arbitrary-set-of-bases). Consider $\mathbb{N}_2$, the set of natural numbers greater than or equal to $2$. I define a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}_2$ to be a "possible base set", if there exists a real number $r$ which is normal to every base $b$ in $S$, and not normal to every base $b$  in the complement of $S$ with respect to $\mathbb{N}_2$. My question is, what is a useful necessary and sufficient condition for a subset of $\mathbb{N}_2$ to be a possible base set? I know that not every subset of $\mathbb{N}_2$ is a possible base set.

Comment: Possibly (I'm just quickly providing a possible reference without spending time thinking about what you're asking) something in the answer and/or comments (and the links in them) in the mathoverflow question [Does normalcy in one base imply normalcy in any other base?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/414361/15780) could be of use.